# How to make stacked barplot with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
data = {
    'day': ['Thur', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Sun'],
    'sex': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female'],
}

mydata= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to make a stacked barplot. Day on the x-axis and gender on the y-axis. I want to plot the percentage label (percentage per column).